# Is there a standard way to selectively inherit methods from a Perl superclass?

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance

Or: Is there a standard way to create subclass but make certain methods from the superclass yield a "Can't locate object method" error when called?

For example, if `My::Foo` inherits from `My::Bar`, and `My::Bar` has a method called `dostuff`, calling `Foo->new->dostuff` would die with the "Can't locate object method" error in some non-contrived/hackish way.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? It sounds lilke `My::Bar` isn't the best choice as a superclass and you should abstract its common functionality into a class which can then be used as a parent to your new class.

Comment: Or better yet use roles to compose your classes with shared behaviors.  IMO, Inheritance is overrated and overused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the superclass is a Moose class you could use remove_method.

```
package My::Foo;
use Moose;
extends 'My::Bar';

# some code here

my $method_name = 'method_to_remove';

__PACKAGE__->meta->remove_method($method_name);

1;
```

This is documented in [Class::MOP::Class](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/Class-MOP-1.12/lib/Class/MOP/Class.pm) and should work with [MooseX::NonMoose](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/MooseX-NonMoose-0.20/lib/MooseX/NonMoose.pm) but i am not sure.

Answer (score 5):

You can create dummy methods in your child class that intercept the method calls and die.

```
package My::Foo;
our @ISA = 'My::Bar';
use Carp ();

for my $method qw(dostuff ...) {
    no strict 'refs';
    *$method = sub {Carp::croak "no method '$method' on '$_[0]'"};
}
```

You could even write a module to do this:

```
package No::Method;
use Carp ();
sub import {
    my $class = shift;
    my $caller = caller;

    for my $method (@_) {
        no strict 'refs';
        *{"$caller\::$method"} = sub {
              Carp::croak "no method '$method' on '$_[0]'"
         };
    }
}
```

And then to use it:

```
package My::Foo;
our @ISA = 'My::Bar';
use No::Method qw(dostuff);
```

Comment: I should have clarified: a dummy method that dies is what I meant by a "contrived" way. Would deleting a method from the symbol table yield the particular error automatically?

Comment: The only place where the method is in the symbol table is in the parent package, and deleting it there would make objects of the parent package no longer work.  There really isn't a good way of selectively inheriting in Perl.  You could create an intermediate package that imports only some of the methods from a parent class, and then inherit from that (but that also involves symbol table manipulation).

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on the way My::Bar and My::Foo are constructed. If they are your modules you may want to look into [Exporter.](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html)

You can also import select functions from a class like so:

```
use POSIX qw{setsid};
```